# Irreducibility of polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(i)$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I was thinking about how to show whether or not a polynomial irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ could be irreducible over $\mathbb Q(i)$

I am aware of $x^4 + 1$ being irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ but not $\mathbb Q(i)$. However, it also has strictly complex roots. I was wondering if whenever there are only two non real roots and at least one real root, that the polynomial is irreducible over both $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(i)$.

Are there any more examples of polynomials irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ but not $\mathbb Q(i)$ that have only two complex roots and at least one real root? I've realised that my original reasoning is actually flawed but I still suspect that maybe there isn't such a polynomial.

Also, a related question:

I am aware of many tests for irreducibility over $\mathbb Q$, but what I can I do other than check the roots, to see that a polynomial is or isn't irreducible over $\mathbb Q(i).$ I am aware that Eisenstein's criterion may be generalised to integral domains, but what if the constant of the polynomial is $2$? In that case Eisenstein wouldn't apply, so is there anything else that I could do?

Comment: $x^2+1$ is a slightly easier example than yours, and the first I thought of before reading your entire question. Still has the same problems, though.

Comment: What do you make of $x^4-3$ and $x^4-5$?

Comment: @MarkBennet: Why, yes! The day after New Year's Day can be hard sometimes…

Comment: [Newton's polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) gives an occasionally useful extension of Eisenstein's criterion. The condition is that if the polygon of a degree $n$ polynomial consists of a single line segment with slope $-a/n,\gcd(a,n)=1$, then the polynomial is irreducible. Consider, for example, $p(x)=x^5-4x+2$ over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$  and the valuation related to the prime $p=1+i$. The constant term is divisible by $p^2$, the linear with $p^4$, and the leading with $p^0$. The polygon thus reduces to a line with slope $-2/5$ and we are done.

Comment: (cont'd) Compare with [this segment from WP on Eisenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Advanced_explanation).

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ be irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ but not over $\Bbb Q(i)$.
Then over $\Bbb Q(i)$ we have the factorisation
$f=g\overline g$ where the coefficients of $\overline g$
are the complex conjugates of those of $g$. The zeroes of $\overline g$
the complex conjugates of those of $g$. A real zero of $f$ is then both a zero of $g$ and of $\overline g$ and so a double zero of $f$, which
we'd assumed irreducible...

Comment: Does this imply that $f$ is of even degree, since $g, \bar g$ would have the same degree? I'm also not really sure what your response implies. What is the importance of this double root?

Comment: @user366818 If $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ but not over $\Bbb Q(i)$ that it has even degree. A polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ with a multiple root cannot be irreducible.